# replacing string with character in C

Tags: c, string, strstr

**The code takes user input(html tag)**

```
ex:
<p> The content is &nbsp; text only &nbsp; inside tag </p>

gets(str);
```

Task is to replace all `&nbsp;` occurences with a `newline("\n")`

```
while((ptrch=strstr(str, "&nbsp;")!=NULL)
{
  memcpy(ptrch, "\n", 1);
}

printf("%s", str);
```

The code above replaces only first character with `\n`.

Query is how to replace entire `&nbsp;` with `\n` or how to set rest of `nbsp;` to something like empty character constant without terminating string with null pointer('\0').

Comment: @sukhvir that's part of str (user input using gets)

Comment: just a suggestion ..don't use  `gets()` .. use `fgets` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Now just use `memmove` to move the memory left to the new line.

```
char str[255];
char* ptrchr;
char* end;

gets(str); // DANGEROUS! consider using fgets instead
end = (str + strlen(str));

while( (ptrch=strstr(str, "&nbsp;")) != NULL)
{
    memcpy(ptrch, "\n", 1);
    memmove(ptrch + 1, ptrch + sizeof("&nbsp;") - 1, end-ptrchr);
}

printf("%s", str);
```

Comment: Sorry could you please specify the parameters also

Comment: This could be optimized somewhat by moving not everything but only up to next `&nbsp;`. Then you move from second to third by 10 characters etc.

Comment: Why `strcpy` is going to work? We're dealing with overlapping memory here.

Comment: @aragaer No. Overlapping may be only when you move memory to right, not to left.

Comment: @Zaffy doesn't it depend on implementation?

Comment: @aragaer take a look [here](http://imgur.com/kDqhcRg) you see ?  THe cursor is moving forward and so the data. It is safe. If you would move to the right it may be dangerous.

Comment: @Zaffy, that's what I am saying - it does depend on implementation of strcpy, which is not guaranteed to be safe for any overlapping areas. Manpage clearly states that "strings may not overlap". One example of what might go wrong is that strcpy will not copy byte-by-byte and will attempt more efficient moves of larger size. There are ways to do that.

Comment: @aragaer Hm now i see, you're right. But if the space between src and dest is large enough even word-size writes won't make any mess. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of memcpy you could directly set the character to '\n': `*ptchr = '\n';` And after that use memmove to move the rest of the line left - you replaced 6 characters with 1, so you have to move the line by 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
    char * ptrch = NULL;
    int len =0;
    while(NULL != (ptrch=strstr(str, "&nbsp;")))
    {
      len = strlen(str) - strlen(ptrch);
      memcpy(&str[len],"\n",1);
      memmove(&str[len+1],&str[len+strlen("&nbsp;")],strlen(ptrch ));   
    }
```